# Angularjs ng-repeat filter second param

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have this code:

```
ng-repeat="m in measures | filter:{propname:value}:true"
```

This is a dumb question, but I couldn't find an answer in the docs or net.
What is `true` doing at the end of filter?

Answer (score 1):

OK, LOL find my answer here
http://sarahbranon.com/post/69604997957/fun-with-angularjs-filters-part-1-the-filter

its a `comparator`

> The comparator is the optional second
>   argument to the filter filter. When the comparator is a boolean value,
>   it determines whether to do an exact comparison (using angular.equals)
>   or a (case-insensitive) substring match– the default is false
>   (non-strict)